# How to prevent users from SELECTing all rows in a table by using Row Level Security in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Ive got a question about row level security in MSSQL 2016 Standard Edition.

The issue is;

- We are currently using MSSQL 2012 SE. We have tables that has
  sensitive data in it and we have users who should reach those tables
  in a limited access.
- We are now preventing them to select all the data in those tables by
  giving them a stored procedure to select that table so that procedure
  gives the result of the TOP 5 of the query (by setting ROWCOUNT = 5
  in the SP) . So these users always can select top 5 rows of the
  query.
- As we are upgrading MSSQL from 2012 to 2016 SE this week, i wonder if
  we can do this process by using Row Level Security ? I have
  researched about it, and i couldn't find a way to set ROWCOUNT = 5 in
  the inline table valued function.
- I just need to prevent some users to select all the table even though
  they want to. And i also dont want them to select the table by using
  a stored procedure or something like that.

  Is there a better solution to do so in sql 2016 ?

Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are worried about some weird scenarios. If you provide an SP for users - can't you implement your restriction logic in it? Or you are a DBA and you don't trust even to developers?

Comment: @IvanStarostin You should not trust anybody if you are a DBA. I am managing databases that has lots of credit card and customer sensitive informations. And this scenario is not for developers, but for support team.

Comment: ...your support team is allowed to make ad-hoc selects from tables with extremely sensitive data?

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes but they can get just 5 of the results so that they should give the right where clauses to get spesific data they want..

Comment: Row level security is intended to block or allow access to rows based on data values, not row counts - this isn't a good fit for your use case, unless you want to restrict the users to only ever see the same five rows. If you aren't happy with your current solution, you could alternatively use views with a `TOP 5` clause.

Comment: @EdHarper There is no way to give the view the where conditions that the user gave if i use TOP 5 in view.

Comment: @YasinBilir- correct - the user would have to write their own `WHERE` clause - which they would have to do with any solution which isn't based on a stored procedure or a function. I (wrongly) guessed that this was a reason you wanted to move away from your current solution.

Comment: @EdHarper I got your point. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Perhaps [Dynamic Data Masking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130841.aspx) could help you. Hide sensitive values from the support team by masking the data instead of limiting the rows.

Comment: @JodyT yes i thought about that too, but in that way, they will not able to see first 5 rows. They should at least see couple of rows to do the work. Thats why i have been using ROWCOUNT for this..I think there is no way to do what i want.. Thanks for the answers anyway.